# I re-installed sane and xsane but my /etc/sane.d/ folder does not contain a dll.conf (nor anything else)

Tags: scanner, sane, xsane

After my first try to get my Samsung SCX-3200 scanner to work I wanted to try a fresh start. So I removed all installed packages, the /etc/sane.d/ folder and the ~/.sane folder. Then I re-installed the sane/xsane packages as recommended here in STEP 1: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane
The problem is that my /etc/sane.d/ folder is now completely empty apart from a folder dll.d which is also empty. What did I do wrong? Which package installs the dll.conf file (and the according vendor.conf files)?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The package containing 'dll.conf' is `libsane-common`, as found [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=dll.conf&mode=exactfilename&suite=cosmic&arch=any)  this should have been installed if you also installed sane-utils, as mentioned in 'step 1'

Comment: Please the the command `sudo apt install --reinstall sane sane-utils libsane-extras xsane`, and copy any errors that occur into your question.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for the tips. `libsane-common` had already been installed. When I ran the reinstall command no errors occurred, but there was still no content in `/etc/sane.d/`.

Comment: I just tried uninstalling `libsane-common` and deleted the folder `/etc/sane.d/`. Then I reinstalled `libsane-common` (and all other packages that had been removed with it). Now the folder `/etc/sane.d/` was re-created but still there is no content.

Comment: I just tried what you did, and ended with the same result.  My read is that libsane-common should install the dll files, but has not.  Perhaps you should submit a bug report on this?

Comment: Thanks for verifying this @CharlesGreen! I'll file a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the cause of your problem here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450465/behavior-of-files-defined-in-conffiles

The files that `libsane-common` puts in `/etc/sane.d` are marked in deb as a config files. They aren't deleted when the packages are removed with `apt remove` or `dpkg -r`. And they aren't installed back with `apt install` or `dpkg -i` after that. So if you deleted them manually - you lost them. I suspect the list of config files for each package is kept in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/*.conffiles` between installations.
The `apt purge` and `dpkg --purge` do complete deletion of all package files including config files. So the best way to solve your problem is:

```
sudo apt purge libsane-common
sudo apt install sane skanlite xsane simple-scan sane-util
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hey truf, thanks for the help! It works now!